# attr(x) not working in CSS

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-content

So I would like to use `pre` tags in a documentation web page. Now, I want the correct language to be in the top right corner. So This is what I thought I could do:

```
<pre class="code" language="Python"></pre>
```

then I could use `after` and `attr(X)` in CSS to fill the psuedo after with the content of `language`:

```
pre.code:after{
    content: attr("language");
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
```

But this is not doing anything!

if I change `attr("language")` to `"Python"` it works...why does attr(X) not work here?

## [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pcy7N/)

Comment: You should prefer `data-` attributes over your own made up ones.

Comment: The attribute `language` is not valid. HTML5 CR suggests that you use `class=language-python` instead, but if you must have the name of the language available as attribute value in CSS, use `data-language=Python`.

Comment: I understand that now...I actually used language to simply show my problem so it would be more comprehensible. What is the reason for using a class rather than an attribute...an attribute seems like it would be better for something like this

Comment: Using a class means using an attribute – a valid attribute (the `class` attribute). Using a `language` attribute would be particularly risky, as such a name could well be defined in some future HTML version, causing nasty surprises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't include quotations within the [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) expression.

Use `attr(language)` as opposed to `attr("language")`.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/STE4W/) - your code now works with that minor correction.

```
pre.code:after {
    content: attr(language);
}
```

See [@BoltClock's comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505799/attrx-not-working-in-css?rq=1#comment29153818_19505837) for details as to *why* quotations aren't suppose to be used.

Comment: @RyanSaxe Sometimes quotes are needed when a value contains spaces (for example `font-family:"Helvetica Neue", "Comic Sans";`) but there is no such thing as an HTML attribute name that contains spaces.

Comment: Yes I understand that, and because of that I have always thought that quotes can't hurt while not using them can...I guess it can go both ways

Comment: `attr()` is not an attribute selector, or a selector at all for that matter. It's a function, only valid as a value. As such, Selectors doesn't cover this function; [this section of CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content) does. Note that CSS2.1 doesn't really make any mention of functions in general (which would explain why its definition is hidden away in another section), but it does list a FUNCTION token in the [grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html).

Comment: @Ryan Saxe: The `attr()` function explicitly only accepts an identifier - see my link above. This is why quotations are disallowed. When surrounding text with quotation marks, you're denoting a string. Without them, you're, well, not denoting a string, and usually this means you're denoting an identifier. It's similar in CSS as it is with many languages.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: See above.